# Emacs function to case-insensitive sort-lines?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I know that you can do the following to sort-lines in emacs without case sensitivity:

```
M-x set-variable [RETURN] sort-fold-case [RETURN] t [RETURN]
M-x sort-lines
M-x set-variable [RETURN] sort-fold-case [RETURN] nil [RETURN]
```

But this is annoying to do every time. How can I turn this into a function so that I don't have to do the same thing over and over?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
(defun sort-lines-nocase ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sort-fold-case t))
    (call-interactively 'sort-lines)))
```

Comment: FTR, right after the `(interactive)` line there should be a line `(defvar sort-fold-case)` *(optionally with the default value)*. That is because in this case `sort-fold-case` is a lexical variable, so it's kinda UB that it worked before. And byte-compiling without a `defvar` will result in a complaint `Unused lexical variable ‘sort-fold-case’`. On top of that, latest Emacs built from git will even bail out on that with `custom-declare-variable: Defining as dynamic an already lexical var`.

Answer (score 9):

If you *always* want to sort case insensitive, try this in a file used on startup:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(sort-fold-case t t)
)
```

Then you can just call M-x sort-lines.